# setting up heap memory in jmeter for more than one concurrent script execution

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, heap-memory

Below is my scenario.

I have 2 test scripts :- one might use 5GB to 15GB of heap memory and other script might use from 5GB to 12GB.

If i have a machine of 32 GB memory,

While executing for the first script can i assign XMS 1GB XMX 22GB(though my script needs 15GB) and for the second script can i assign XMS 1GB and XMX 12GB

As sum of maximum goes beyong 32GB(total memory)

In the second case i assign like this--->

for script 1:XMS 22GB XMX 22GB

for script 2:XMS 12GB and XMX 12GB

Sum of Max 34GB.

**Does it by any chance work like below----- >**

If 12GB is assigned for first script,is this memory blocked for that process/script ? and can i not use the unused memory for other processes ?

or

If 12GB is assigned for the first script ,it uses only as much as requuired by it and any other process can use the rest memory ?  IF it works in this way-i don't have to specifically assign heap for two scripts separately.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the minimum heap memory via `Xms` parameter the JVM will **reserve** this memory and it will not be available for other processes.

If you're able to allocate more JVM Heap than you have total physical RAM it means that your OS will go for [swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) - using hard drive to dump memory pages which extends your computer memory at cost of speed because memory operations are fast and disk operations are very slow.

For example look at my laptop which has 8 GB of total physical RAM:

[image]

It has 8 GB of physical memory of which 1.2 GB are free. It means that I can safely allocate 1 GB of RAM to Java

However when I give 8 GB to Java as:

```
java -Xms8G
```

it still works

15 GB - still works

and when I try to allocate 20 GB it fails because it doesn't fit into physical + virtual memory.

You must **avoid swapping** because it means that JMeter will not be able to send requests fast enough even if the system under tests supports it so make sure to measure how much **available** physical RAM you have and your test must not exceed this. If you cannot achieve it on one machine - you will have to go for [distributed testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter/)

Also "concurrently" running 2 different scripts is not something you should be doing because it's not only about the memory, a single CPU core can execute only one command at a time, other commands are waiting in the queue and being served by [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) which is kind of expensive and slow operation.

And last but not the least, allocating the maximum HEAP is not the best idea because this way garbage collections will be less frequent but will last much longer resulting in throughput dropdowns, keep heap usage between 30% and 80% like in [Optimal Heap Size](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Java.html#Java-Garbage_Collection-Optimal_Heap_Size) article

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response Dmitri.
Out of all your valuable response one line is confusing for me--"Also "concurrently" running 2 different scripts is not something you should be doing"   ---->   If i have 2 app to be performance tested and if i have only on Load generator machine.?? you suggest to avoid doing that and suggest to conduct perf test on only one app from one load generator